# Gulp: how to pass parameters from watch to tasks

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

With gulp you often see patterns like this:

```
gulp.watch('src/*.jade',['templates']);

gulp.task('templates', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
    .pipe( livereload( server ));
});
```

Does this actually pass the watch'ed files into the templates task? How do these overwrite/extend/filter the src'ed tasks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same question some time ago and came to the following conclusion after digging for a bit.

`gulp.watch` is an eventEmitter that emits a `change` event, and so you can do this:

```
var watcher = gulp.watch('src/*.jade',['templates']);

watcher.on('change', function(f) {
  console.log('Change Event:', f);
});
```

and you'll see this:

```
Change Event: { type: 'changed',
  path: '/Users/developer/Sites/stackoverflow/src/touch.jade' }
```

This information could presumably be passed to the `template` task either via its task function, or the behavior of `gulp.src`.

The task function itself can only receive a callback (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#fn) and cannot receive any information about vinyl files (https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs) that are used by gulp.

The source starting a task (`.watch` in this case, or gulp command line) has no effect on the behavior of `gulp.src('src-glob', [options])`. `'src-glob'` is a string (or array of strings) and `options` (https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options) has nothing about any file changes.

Hence, I don't see any way in which `.watch` could directly affect the behavior of a task it triggers.

If you want to process only the changed files, you can use `gulp-changed` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed) if you want to use `gulp.watch`, or you cold use `gulp-watch`.

Alternatively, you could do this as well:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.watch('src/*.jade', function(event){
  template(event.path);
});

gulp.task('templates', function() {
  template('src/*.jade');
});

function template(files) {
  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(jade({
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way to pass a parameter or a data from your watcher to a task. I**s through using a global variable**, or a variable that is in both blocks scops. Here is an example:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
        //....
        //json comments 
        watch('./app/tempGulp/json/**/*.json', function (evt) {
             jsonCommentWatchEvt = evt; // we set the global variable first
             gulp.start('jsonComment'); // then we start the task
        })
})

//global variable
var jsonCommentWatchEvt = null

//json comments task

gulp.task('jsonComment', function () {
    jsonComment_Task(jsonCommentWatchEvt)
})
```

And here the function doing the task work in case it interest any one, But know i didn't need to put the work in such another function i could just implemented it directly in the task. And for the file you have your global variable. Here it's `jsonCommentWatchEvt`. But know if you don't use a function as i did, a good practice is to assign the value of the global variable to a local one, that you will be using. And you do that at the all top entry of the task. So you will not be using the global variable itself. And that to avoid the problem that it can change by another watch handling triggering. When it stay in use by the current running task.

```
function jsonComment_Task(evt) {
    console.log('handling : ' + evt.path);
    gulp.src(evt.path, {
        base: './app/tempGulp/json/'
    }).
    pipe(stripJsonComments({whitespace: false})).on('error', console.log).
    on('data', function (file) { // here we want to manipulate the resulting stream

        var str = file.contents.toString()

        var stream = source(path.basename(file.path))
        stream.end(str.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n\n'))
        stream.
        pipe(gulp.dest('./app/json/')).on('error', console.log)
    })
}
```

I had a directory of different json's files, where i will use comments on them. I'm watching them. When a file is modified the watch handling is triggered, and i need then to process only the file that was modified. To remove the comments, i used json-comment-strip plugin for that. Plus that i needed to do a more treatment. to remove the multiple successive line break.  **Whatever, at all first i needed to pass the path to the file that we can recover from the event parameter**. **I passed that to the task through a global variable, that does only that. Allow passing the data.**

Note: Even though that doesn't have a relation with the question, in my example here, i needed to treat the stream getting out from the plugin processing. i used the `on("data"` event. it's asynchronous. so the task will mark the end before the work completely end (the task reach the end, but the launched asynchronous function will stay processing a little more). So the time you will get in the console at task end, isn't the time for the whole processing, but task block end. Just that you know. For me it doesn't matter.